# Generating my own XYZ tiles, how do x,y,z map to GPS bounds?

Tags: xyz-tiles

I'm writing some software that has DSM data that I'd like to turn into an XYZ tile server so I can plug it into Leaflet, but I can't for the life of me find any information on how x, y, and z values translate to (GPS) bounding box coordinates so I can respond with the correct crops. Is this documented anywhere?

(Mind, I'm not looking for how to create complete tilesets using QGIS or GDAL or the like, I have large masters that I can cut up realtime-enough just fine, I'm just trying to find the information that explains how {x}/{y}/{z} translates to bounds, and google is completely failing me)

Comment: Try a library like https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile It might help to search proper terms. XYZ tiles are typically made from data in a special projection (https://epsg.io/3857) which has the nice property of being square and therefore able to subdivided into squares. This really has nothing to do with GPS.

Comment: See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

Comment: @TomazicM cheers

Comment: @alphabetasoup it has things to do with GPS in the sense that GPS is shorthand for lat/long coordinates, which I need to know in order to crop my files.

Comment: I think you're confusing GPS (the technology) and the concept of a geographic coordinate reference system (CRS). It may be in some shorthand lexicon, but it's still confusing and also probably why you were having problems finding things in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [OSM wiki page for "slippy map" tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames), XYZ tiles use the Web Mercator projection (WGS84/EPSG:3857), with a tile `x,y,z` having an inclusive North-West corner `x,y,z` and exclusive South-East corner `x+1,y+1,z`, and the mapping formulae for going from `x,y,z` triplet to `lat,long` coordinate being:

```
n = 2^z
a = π(1 - 2y/n)
lat = deg(arctan(sinh(a)))
long = 360x/n - 180
```